# Unable to correlate dynamic value from one sub request to another sub request at jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I can retrieve dynamic value from one sub request but unable to pass that dynamic value to next sub request. I am new to Jmeter. Could you please help me.

Comment: Show your test plan and requests

Answer (score 0):

If you extract it using a Regular Expression Extractor with variable name: "variable" [image]

You can use it later in a request as : ${variable}
[image]